I am Using speech_recognition module but it giving me this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aifc'
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Talk")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("Time over, thanks")
    try:
        print("Text: "+r.recognize_google(audio_text))
    except:
         print("Sorry, I did not get that")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\sp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import aifc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aifc'

I don't know what's happening here. I have also reinstalled the library and the python also but I giving me same error, so please help me!

Looks like 'aifc' was part of the python standard library, but was removed in python 3.13.0.
Rolling back to python 3.12.7 fixes the issue, until SpeechRecognition is able to resolve/workaround the issue.
The issue may also be resolved by adding a 3rd party replacement library, like https://pypi.org/project/standard-aifc/
pip install standard-aifc

Note: I haven't verified the authenticity of that this pip library, or its maintainer.

standard-aifc didn't solve my issue but it worked after switch back to Python 3.12.3
